# Cannot Find Gulp Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason, when i type `gulp` in the terminal, my gulp modules can't be found.
All of the commands `node -v`, `gulp -v` and `npm -v` work fine and i have the latest versions.
I ran this commands but it still won't work.

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm install -g gulp
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

This is my project, https://github.com/DannyS95/Project
I also tried to run the same project on my windows volume and the gulp command works fine, it just won't work on ubuntu, i am dual booting.

Comment: Can you add the exact command you're running and its output?

Comment: i type gulp : module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-plumber'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/Documentos/prime-factors/Gulpfile.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3

Comment: `gulp-plumber` is not installed, per your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not commit `node_modules/` unless you have need.
2. The error message says you do not have `gulp-plumber` installed. If you look in your `package.json`, there does not exist a package named `gulp-plumber`, so install it.

Comment: Hey mate, i got i working, i just had to use the command npm install after the npm install gulp-plumber and it worked, thank you so much bro :D

Comment: If you have gulp installed globally, then it should execute the gulp file by just running `gulp` in the working directory. Otherwise you'll need to add a npm script to execute gulp: `"test": "gulp"`

Comment: I have it globally so i won't run into any issues. I am a beginner and am still learning php, i don't know any js for now so that is why this is confusing to me. Anyway you saved me big time, i was stuck for 3 days now i can keep on learning :D